# Need working example of how to call/consume Java Web service from an Android Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, web, wsdl

I am new to android development and need to connect to Server and get the info or values to the Android activity.Please provide a working example of how to call/consume a java Web Service from an Android Activity.

Here is what I have done so far.

Created an Android Activity.
Created class in eclipse that calculates the Area given radius and returns the value. 
Created a web service for the above class and tested using WebService Explorer and it works. The Web Service uses port 11144 for the request and 8080 for the response.

The questions I have are:
Do I use the wsdl or use Java client as a stub?
If I need to use the stub, Is it like just another impor like any other java class ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example of "how to call/consume a web service from an Android Activity"

That is the class who contact the service :

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Log;

public class WebService extends SoapObject {

    // a remplacer par les bonnes informations
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetChampionRotationWeek";

    // a remplacer par les bonnes informations
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetChampionRotationWeek";

    // a remplacer par les bonnes informations
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    // a remplacer par les bonnes informations
    private static final String URL = "http://www.thinkdroid.eu/WebService1.asmx";

    public WebServiceLogin(String namespace, String name) {
        super(namespace, name);
    }

    public String getResult(){
        String resultat = "";
        try {
            SoapObject requete = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            //Soap version 1.1
            SoapSerializationEnvelope enveloppe = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            // Codé en dotNet ou non ?
            enveloppe.dotNet = true;
            enveloppe.setOutputSoapObject(requete);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, enveloppe);
            resultat = enveloppe.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultat;
    }
}
```

And that is the méthod who instantiate and use this class :

```
try {
    WebService serviceConnexion = new WebService("http://tempuri.org/", "WebService1Soap");
    result = serviceConnexion.getResult();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use this lib to contact the service : 
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Source : http://www.thinkdroid.eu/?p=192 (French website)

I hope I have help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all this following Method to call web services in android

```
public String postData(String result, JSONObject obj) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            String InsertTransactionResult = null;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 1000);

            try {

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(result.toString());
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httppost.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InsertTransactionResult = EntityUtils
                        .toString(response.getEntity());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return InsertTransactionResult;
        }

        public String putData(String result, JSONObject obj) {

            // Create a new HttpClient and Put Header

            String UpdateTransactionResult = null;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

            try {

                HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(result.toString());
                httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httpPut.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
                UpdateTransactionResult = EntityUtils
                        .toString(response.getEntity());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return UpdateTransactionResult;

        }


        public String deleteRecord(String result) {

            // Create a new HttpClient and Get Header

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(result.toString());

            try {
                HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 0);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpDelete);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                System.out.println(response.toString());
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(LoginActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to Authenticate");
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }



    public String getMethod(String result) {

            // Create a new HttpClient and Get Header

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(result.toString());

            try {
                HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 0);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 0);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                System.out.println(response.toString());
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(LoginActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to Authenticate");
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. Please tell me how do I pass parameters to Java method and get the result back.

Comment: just call this method like postData("your web URL","your data whatever you want to save in database");

Comment: you have methods in your webservice to interect with sever you can make url using this methods and pass this as perameter in methods as i mention above